# The material surface selection field is not available in 2.79b

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface

A tutorial is telling me to assign the material to glossy, but my version of blender 2.79b, is completely different from his version of blender 2.79. How can I select a glossy texture using my version of blender? Which version of Blender can I change to which will be the [same as his version](https://youtu.be/z345CH5DsWc?t=230)?

Thanks for your help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to switch from *Blender Render* engine to *Cycles Render*:

[image]